# SoapUI - Syntactical error in REST JSON

Tags: json, rest, soapui

I am trying to run a login REST service in SoapUIPro with jason.

But I am getting the following syntactical error.

It's working fine when I switch to xml

Request

```
POST http://122.122.232.112/services/public/login HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: application/json
Content-Length: 115
Host: 122.122.232.112
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)

{
  "com.abc.dmb.cons.model.LoginInfo": {
    "userId": "cons31312061521360",
    "password": "Arif#1212"
  }
}
```

Response

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Date: Fri, 06 Dec 2013 05:02:59 GMT
Vary: Accept-Charset, Accept-Encoding, Accept-Language, Accept
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Server: abcd.setup.com.au
Content-Type: application/json;charset=ISO-8859-1
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: close

{"errorCode":"400","errorDescription":"The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect."}
```

Please clarify

Cheers

Comment: Could you provide some code of the service?

Comment: unfortunately I don't have access to the service code. Could it be a service code issue? Even though `xml ` format request are working fine

Comment: Did you try to change first letters of nodes from lower case to upper case?

Comment: Did try but no success

Comment: If this is still relevant, could you post the XML Request that you say works.